# Como eu faço para a função nao retornar o valor se o numero não for binário

Tags: javascript, funções, map, números-binários

Estou tentando fazer um limitador para que toda vez que o usuário digite um numero que não é binário, receba um alerta com a mensagem "Escreva um número binário" porem o problema é que o código envia a mensagem, mas continua executando a função

```
function Bin2Dec ()
{
    const numeros = document.getElementById("char-input").value;
    if (numeros === '') 
    {
        return alert("Por favor, escreva um numero binário");
    }
    numeros.split('').map((char) => {
        if (char !== '0' && char !== '1') return alert("Por favor, escreva um numero binário");
    });
    const decimal = parseInt( numeros, 2 );
    document.getElementById("convertido").innerHTML = numeros + " na base decimal é: " + decimal;        
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para quem quiser ver o site https://sancheesandre.github.io/Bin2Dec/

Answer (score 1):

Ola @SancheesDev tudo bom?

A lógica esta correta, o problema em questão é que ao fazer a verificação dentro do `map` da lista o `return` irá ocorrer apenas para o escopo do map. Recomendo fazer a validação na mesma função em questão. Como por exemplo:

```
function Bin2Dec ()
{
    const numeros = document.getElementById("char-input").value;
    if (numeros === '') 
    {
        return alert("Por favor, escreva um numero binário");
    }

    const hasNonBinaryDigits = numeros.split('').some(char => char !== '0' && char !== '1');
    if(hasNonBinaryDigits) { 
       return alert("Por favor, escreva um numero binário");
    }

    const decimal = parseInt( numeros, 2 );
    document.getElementById("convertido").innerHTML = numeros + " na base decimal é: " + decimal;        
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado! Eu sou novo não programação então ainda estou entendendo como o "map" funciona. tentei de varias formas separar o código, mas sem êxito haha